# Cannot set property of undefined (input[text] value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, input

I can't get the value property from `input[type='text']` `#page-name` and `#page-url`, it shows up undefined :

```js
 eventsDispatcher: function() {

   var self = this;

   $(".b-row a").click(function() {

     var tileId = ("this").id;
     $("#tile-edit").css("display", "block");

     $("#tile-edit-save").click(function() {

       self.pageList[tileId].name = $("#page-name").val(); // -> here
       self.pageList[tileId].url = $("#page-url").val(); // -> here
       console.log(self.pageList[tileId].name);
     });
   });
 },
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="tile-edit">

  <form>
    <table>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="page-url">Adress</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="page-url" id="page-url" class="">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="page-name">Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="page-name" id="page-name" class="">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" id="tile-edit-save" value="save">
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </form>

</div>
```

The rest of the script is working fine, like the both .click functions, just can't figure out why it doesn't get the `#page-name` and `#page-url` values ??

Comment: If you can't 'set a property' of undefined, the undefined element is `self.pageList[tileId]`. What is `("this").id`? That should be `undefined` I think (unless you defined an `id` property for the `String` prototype).

Comment: Of course it is, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just guessing, but `("this").id` should be `undefined`. You might want to change it for:

```
var tileId = $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have special characters in your HTML. I copied and pasted it to/from a plain text editor and it works fine. Try copying and pasting the `form` HTML here.

```js
$('#tile-edit-save').on('click',function() {
console.log($("#page-name").val())
console.log($("#page-url").val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form>
  <table>

    <tr>
      <td><label for="page-url">Adress</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="page-url" id="page-url" class=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><label for="page-name">Name</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="page-name" id="page-name" class=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" id="tile-edit-save" value="save"></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
```